# How to setup a HTTPS Proxy on a raspberry pi

Tags: linux, proxy, ssl, https, squid

I'm looking for a way to encrypt every data sent from my smartphone and laptop by using a proxy server on my raspberry pi.

What I've got so far:
- RPi with Squid3 Running

What I'm still missing:
- Encryption for every http requests that are made from a client

I've tried various guides, but didn't get squid running with SSL Support or sth like that...
Is there any guide that I can follow, since I'm pretty new to RPi and Linux in general?

Thanks really much in advance!

Best regards,

cosi

Comment: if you want to encrypt everything, then a vpn is for that.  I've heard that ssh can be bent to that but not sure how. And ssl wouldn't afaik. But VPNs are built for that.

Comment: your first paragraph says encrypt every data, but later paragraph just menitions http requests

Comment: And you should show what you tried with squid, and what hasn't worked. also this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151192/how-to-configure-https-support-in-squid3

Comment: Possibly off topic but possibly useful: For a very quick SOCKS proxy `ssh -D9999 <raspberry pi hostname>` then setting your browser SOCKS proxy as localhost:9999 will route all web traffic through the Pi, encrypted using SSH.

Answer (score -1):

If the client is talking to a site that speaks HTTP, but not HTTPS, you can't "make" it speak HTTPS.  The site itself has to support HTTPS.  Many sites support HTTP and HTTPS, but there are a few out there that still only do HTTP.

IMHO, this is better addressed with a browser addin, but Squid lets you filter requests through a script that can rewrite those requests.  So you can do something like [this, excerpted below](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200804/0430.html):

```
Here's how I do exactly that. In squid.conf: 
    url_rewrite_program /usr/local/bin/rewrite-http 
and then: 

% cat /usr/local/bin/rewrite-http 
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# 
# URL rewriter for squid to convert HTTP requests to HTTPS. 
# Return an HTTP permanent redirect back to the browser. 
# http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidRedirectors 
# 
$| = 1; 
while (<>) { 
        s/^http:/301:https:/; # replace "http" with "https" 
        print; 
}
```

But it will break any site that doesn't have an HTTPS equivalent at the same domain name.

You could make that script a little more elaborate and have it check against a list of known domains, and only redirect those.  Note however, since every HTTP request goes through the proxy, it could slow things down for everyone using the proxy, especially on a low-powered system like a Raspberry Pi.